# Hovering over tab link does not fill entire tab

Tags: html, css

Hello I am having trouble with my tabs on my website. This is the CSS:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #585858;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background: #AAA;
    padding: 10px;
}
#menu {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #3F3F3F;
}
#menu a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

However, when I hover over a tab it looks like this (top bar is normal, bottom bar is when you hover over a tab): https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9g6i.png Notice the gray area not filling in the box, and it pushes everything to the right of it a few pixels for some reason.

I'm sure there's a very simple fix, help is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest copying and pasting everything from the #menu li to the #menu li a:hover so that everything stays consistent except for the color change. Or take the padding out of #menu li a:hover, which could be causing the problem.

Comment: And as silly as this sounds, if you could get it into a JsFiddle, then I could work on it even more for you.

Comment: for DHTML you should make a fiddle

Comment: here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M3S5c/

Comment: Instead of the padding to the li item, give it to the anchor tag. that will work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M3S5c/10/ have updated the fiddle for you, check it and let me know

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M3S5c/21/ check this out..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving padding to `li` item and hovering `a` will never give you the result you desire. Instead what you can do is, remove padding from the `li` element altogether and give the same padding to the `anchor` tag. That covers the entire area yet retaining the visual dimensions as required.

Check out the pen [here](http://codepen.io/praveenpuglia/pen/bxuJC).

Comment: @Amarnath I believe you are talking about the rest of the black area. If you inspect the element properly that's the background of the `menu` div and not the whole `li` element. According to the asked question this is the answer @user2917393 was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to change the background when the user hovers over the li instead of over the a.

change

```
#menu li a:hover {
    background: #AAA;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

to

```
#menu li:hover {
    background: #AAA;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Doing that doesn't fill the entire box, it only highlights the word.
http://i.imgur.com/3WbPdQm.png thats what i see

Comment: yours is good, but i wanted the link to cover the entire box. your solution still only makes the actual word clickable, not the entire box.